# Fixed Header Disappears

Tags: css, html, header, z-index

I have two fixed headers, named as divs, one below the other. The second one disappears. Is there something in the following CSS that explains its disappearance?

```
#LayoutDiv1 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10001;
    background:#FFF
}

#LayoutDiv3 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 30px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background:#FFF
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div id="LayoutDiv1">Hi</div>
<form action="website.php" method="POST">
<div id="LayoutDiv3">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="user"/>
    Gender<FONT COLOR="#FF0000">*</FONT>
    <select name="Gender[]" double="double">
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind providing the HTML as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `#LayoutDiv3` to be vertically below `#LayoutDiv1`, you need to set `#LayoutDiv3`'s `top` property to 75px. If you want it to appear with a higher depth, like toward the user viewing the screen, you need to set it to a higher `z-index` than the other div.

Right now it is actually appearing underneath `#LayoutDiv1`, since you have them stacked on top of each other and `#LayoutDiv1`'s z-index is higher.

Answer (score 1):

You have made the second Fixed Header to be `height: 30px` and `z-index: 10000`, which will make it hide behind the first one.

If you need to show the second header above the first one, make the `z-index: 10002`.

And if you need to show it below first one, then set the top to atleast the height of the first one, i.e `top: 75px`

**EDIT**

As you need the divs one after another, this should be your final approach,

```
#LayoutDiv1 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10001;
    background:#FFF
}

#LayoutDiv3 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 30px;
    top: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10001;
    background:#FFF
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `header` elements are there.

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz39d/)**

To solve this situation, just change the CSS rules for #LayoutDiv3, as follows:

```
#LayoutDiv3 {
   background: red;
   z-index: 10001;
}
```

And change the `z-index` property for #LayoutDiv1 to "10000".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
#LayoutDiv1 {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```